# Is there anyway to override the Server DateTime at the Custom List Level

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a Global Site that has multiple custom lists that all operate at different regions.

Server is in US Central Time

On one custom list (example) the people are all in Singapore Time so when they load the NewForm.aspx file the date pickers can show the wrong date which is confusing.

I need a way in code in the .aspx to force the DatePicker to use the users local time and not the server time for the datepickers.

sample code

```
 <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff63{$Pos}" controlmode="New" fieldname="TRIAGE_Date" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff63',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@TRIAGE_Date')}" />
```

Comment: How/where would you specify which time zone each list should be in? Would you be happy hard coding this into each form (application page)?

Comment: really like this thread but was hoping for a practical example.  In my situation I have a custom sharepoint designer 2010 form "new".  I have multiple standard sp2010 datepicker  fields that unfortunately use the servers date/time (USA ET) and one of my lists is regional to Singapore SGT.  How do I get the date dropdowns to be in sync with SGT especially the now portion.

Comment: would have no problem hard coding this in each page if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a custom list for which you can have custom forms where all your users are in Singapore, this solution should be acceptable.

You can use the `TimeZoneInfo` class. You'll get the current UTC date/time. Then convert it to Singapore date/time. Then set it as the default value of the date picker control.

```
TimeZoneInfo singaporeStandardTime = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Singapore Standard Time");
DateTime singaporeNow = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, singaporeStandardTime);
YourDatePickerControl.SelectedDate = singaporeNow.Date;
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c) for a full list of all time zone ids.

EDIT:

It seems it's possible to set the `TimeZoneID` property of a `DateTimeControl` directly:

```
YourDateTimeControl.TimeZoneID = 4100; // 4100 is for Singapore
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047%28v=winembedded.10%29.aspx) for a full list of all time zone locales/ids.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint internally stores time in UTC. The datetime fields use the website´s Region Settings to Display/accept entries. 
All you could do is make a Website for each Region with ist list on it.

Comment: has to be a way around this... has anyone seen the date time field recoded?

Comment: of course you could make your own control used in your form, which Shows the date in the way you want to. However, anywhere else where the date is shown the SharePoint-standard-way (listviews, search results, ...) the date will be shown according to the webs Region settings